# How to write to a textfile in one Activity & read that file in another Activity?

Tags: android, file, read-write

I am able to write and then read a text file in the SAME activity, but I am unable to read a text file after writing to it from another Activity.

***Ex:*** **Activity A** creates and writes to a text file. **Activity B** reads that text file.

I use this code to write to the text file in **Activity A**:

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
        OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
        try 
        {
            fos = openFileOutput("user_info.txt", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
            osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
            osw.write("text here");
            osw.close();
            fos.close();
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And then I use this code to try and read the same text file created by **Activity A**, but I get a `FileNotFoundException`:

```
            try 
            {
                FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("user_info.txt");
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
                BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String line;
                while((line = buff.readLine()) != null)
                {

                    Toast.makeText(this, line, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Does anyone know why I am getting the `FileNotFoundException`?

Is it a path issue?

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know how is built your application, but, the error you get does seem like a path issue, are you sure both Activities are in the same folder ? 
If not, you'll need to set either an abolute path (like : "/home/user/text.txt") for the text file or a relative path (like : "../text.txt").
If you're not sure, try to print the current path for the Activity using some command like

```
new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
```

And, although I can't say I'm expert with Android, are you sure you need the Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE for your file ? If no other application than yours is reading or writing from/to it, it should not be necessary, right ?

Answer (score 0):

it is surealy a path issue.
 you can write like this

```
fpath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+"yourdirectory";

File custdir=new File(fpath);
if(!custdir.exists())
        {
            custdir.mkdirs();

        }
                    File savedir=new File(custdir.getAbsolutePath());
                    File file = new File(savedir, filename);

                    if(file.exists())
                    {
                        file.delete();
                    }
                    FileOutputStream fos;
                    byte[] data = texttosave.getBytes();
                    try {
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        fos.write(data);
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error File Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e("fnf", ""+e.getMessage());
                        // handle exception
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // handle exception
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error IO Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
```

and you can read like

```
String locatefile=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+"yourdirectory"+"/filename";




try {
            br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(locatefile));
                     while((text=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        body.append(text);
        body.append("\n");

    }
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

 } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```